# Error: Package ae.awt.java does not exist

Tags: java, netbeans, awt, desktop

I've got code that requires the use of the Desktop import on Netbeans, I've downloaded the jar folder ae-awt.jar that contains the import to use. When i've added the import

```
import ae.awt.java.Desktop
```

the program allows me to use it and gives the suggested code after each period, however when I run the program I'm presented with the error "error: package ae.java.awt does not exist
import ae.java.awt.Desktop;"

I don't understand why this is not working as I have added the package to my libraries folder. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: `import ae.awt.java.Desktop` What the.. DYM `import java.awt.Desktop`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the jar is not in your classpath.
Check if you have the jar in project properties > Libraries > Compile tab.
Check also if the jar is specified in the classpath (click on the "Run Ant target" button under the "Repeate Run" button")

Comment: I don't appear to have a compile tab in libraries. All it shows is a checkbox asking "is library" and an empty list of referenced library projects.

Comment: So if you have nothing in this list consider to adding your jar here.

Comment: It's added in the list for the JAR Libraries tab but when I try to add it as a library in the libraries tab it doesn't let me select the folder to add, it just opens it. I think it's because it isn't a project folder but I can't chose to add a different type of folder.